# Изменение элементов при наведении css hover

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при наведении на третий `div` не меняется размер второго `div`, как при наведении на первый `div`.

```css
#block {
width: 50%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 10%;
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background: green;
}
div:nth-child(1):hover {
    width: 80%;
}
div:nth-child(1):hover + div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10%; 
}
div:nth-child(3):hover {
    width: 80%;
}
div:nth-child(3):hover + div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
<div class="div">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
<div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если пользуетесь селекторами, то должны знать, как они работают.

Поведение последующих и вложенных элементов не может влиять на предыдущие элементы и/или родителей.

Но, можно сделать следующим образом:

```css
#block {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 10%;
}

.div:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
.div:nth-child(1):hover { min-width: 80%; }

.div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 80%;
  background: blue;
}

.div:nth-child(3) { background: green; }
.div:nth-child(3):hover { min-width: 80%; }
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `+` это **СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ** элемент. А вы выбираете "следующий, но второй" )

Можете попробовать при `hover` родителю задавать всем дочерним по 10%, а при `hover` на дочерний перебивать свойства родительского ховера

```css
#block {
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 10%;
  background: red;
}
.div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
.div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background: green;
}
#block:hover .div{
    width: 10%;
}

#block .div:hover{
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex 1 не подходит, родительский блок inline-block

Comment: ну поменяйте на inline-flex

Comment: Родительский div имеет inline-block

Comment: И что? Родительский не имеет ширины? А как тогда проценты помогут ?

Comment: Там идет calc, не в процентах все.

Comment: я вообще не понял, что вам там нужно. В примере совершенно по другому.  ну выборка у Вас не правильная. В ответе указал почему

Comment: Родительский элемент не flex, и дочерние тоже. Обновил код.